# Angular: How to change a set of Components from a Service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a set of Components which properties should be changed by a Service. 
The Components have a very small model and are supposed to stay small. 
They are rendered with *ngFor.

The Service has a big Object and should know all components and be able to manipulate their properties.

I have looked and tried out BehaviorSubjects a bit, but what seems a bit wrong to me, is that a small component would listen to a big object:

```
class Service{
    _bigModel: BehaviorSubject<object>
    bigObject: Observable<object> 
}

class Component{
   constructor(){
      bigObject.subscribe((newBigObject)=>{
          let partNeeded = newBigObject.key1.keya.blabla; 
          //...do sth with partNeeded; 
      }); 
   }
}
```

The disadvantages here:

- Components will subscribe events that do not target the component.
- Possibly loads the model of the service into all small components,
  blowing up the DOM. Dont know if the BehaviorSubject is handling
  variable references etc.
- The need for the component to know the model of the Service in order to get what they need to work.

What I thought would make more sense is if the Service could manipulate Components directly:

```
class Service{
    componentList: Component[]; //dunno the type of a Component
    changeComponent(idOfComponent, propertyToChange, value); 
    changeAllComponents(propertyToChange){
       for(c of componentList){
          let val = computeSomeValue(); 
          changeComponent(c, propertyToChange, val); 
       }
    }; 
}

class Component {
     someProperty: someType; 
     someOtherProperty: someType; 
}
//Template: 
<div [ngClass]="someOtherProperty">{{someProperty}}</div>
```

Is this apporach reasonable and possible? In this case, how can I manipulate a specific Component from a service? 
If not, what are better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Go with the first approach. Its basically what NGRX and any redux-based state container/store does, so its a battle-proven concept that works.

Going through your bullet points:

> Components will subscribe events that do not target the component.

This depends of your implementation. You can avoid this by using the correct rxjs operators, for example:

```
Observable<string> stringProperty = this.service.dataChanges()
                                        .pipe(
                                          // extract the property that you need
                                          map(data => ...),
                                          // skip until a different value is emited
                                          distinctUntilChanged()
                                        );
```

> Possibly loads the model of the service into all small components,
>   blowing up the DOM. Dont know if the BehaviorSubject is handling
>   variable references etc.

For the 1st part of this point, I dont know exactly what you mean with this. My guess is that you refer to a case in which the service data object is directly rendered into the DOM, which is a valid use case and you would be responsible for not blowing things up.

For the 2nd part, in an ideal implemetation, **every** data object emited by the service should be a unique *immutable* object. If not, things will get ugly really fast, as components might not pick up *mutations* of the data object made in other sections of your component tree.

> The need for the component to know the model of the Service in order
>   to get what they need to work.

Whats wrong with this?

I wouldnt give your 2nd approach too much thought, as it comes with a lot of issues:

- If you dont define a common component interface, you will be forced to work without type checking (eg: accessing object properties in ways like object["someProperty"])
- If you define a common component interface, for maximum usability you will most likely be forced to expose the service data object, which wont solve your 3rd bullet point.
- Keeping track of components adds complexity, as you will have to correctly register/unregister instances.

Comment: First of thanks for the hint with rxjs operators. What I meant with the Dom blowup is that if you listen to a big object in small and many components like this: this.object.subscribe(newObject =>...); I expect each small component to hold newObject at some point in time. That mean if you have 100 small component you have 100 instances of the newObject. Make it 1000 and the Browser kills you website.

Comment: About the knowledge of the Service model: There are multiple things wrong with this in my opinion. For one it defies the single-responsibility principle. The Service should be responsible for what it offers and the components is responsible for what is shows. Hence the service controls the model and the component does the renderings and eventlistening. Also if you want to change the main object is some way you also need to change the way you subscribe to that nested Objects in the components which I think should not happen there. Also If you consider components that are created with ngFor

Comment: - I rather want those components to have next to no complexity. But what I thought maybe is to provide a subscriber method  from the service that give the component the correct subsciber for what the component asks for. something like //service: provideSubsriber(property){ return Subcriber...} Still have to figure out if and how that can work though.

Comment: About the single-responsibility principle: I dont argue that my second approach satifies that principle either, but it intuitively made more sense to me for a bigger service to control smaller components/services etc.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to modify a Component from a Service directly. Services are used for data or logic that isn't associated with a specific view / Component.

Services shouldn't have knowledge about the Components used throughout your app but just provide access to needed data (typically using Observables). Components should then decide which Service they need to work with and which data from that Service they what to subscribe to.

You could let your Service provide different parts of your big model as separate Observables. Your components then pick the right Observable they need. Components use Services, not the other way around.

Either split up your big model into multiple models / Subjects.
Does all data really have to be in one object, maybe rethink your design.

```js
class Service{
  _model1: BehaviorSubject<object>
  object1: Observable<object>

  _model2: BehaviorSubject<object>
  object2: Observable<object>

  _model3: BehaviorSubject<object>
  object3: Observable<object>   
}
```

Or make some parts of your big model available as their own Observable:

```js
class Service{
  _bigModel: BehaviorSubject<object>
  bigObject: Observable<object>

  object2 = _bigModel.pipe(
    map(newBigObject => newBigObject.key1.keya.blabla),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )

  object3 = _bigModel.pipe(
    pluck('key2', 'keya', 'blabla'),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )  
}
```